# percentile_approx on pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, percentile

I'm new with pySpark.

I have the following spark DF named spark_df:

```
+-------+------------------------+
|item   |item_sum                |
+-------+------------------------+
|  1    |                       1|
|  2    |                       2|
|  3    |                       3|
|  4    |                       4|
|  5    |                       5|
|  6    |                       6|
|  7    |                       7|
+-------+------------------------+
```

when I execute the following:

```
spark_df.select(
    f.expr("percentile_approx(`item_sum`, 0.5, 100)")
).show()
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|percentile_approx(item_sum, CAST(0.5 AS DOUBLE), 100)                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    4|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but when I execute the following:

```
spark_df.where(
    f.expr(f"`item` <= percentile_approx(`item_sum`, 0.5, 100)")
).show()
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: percentile_approx
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try where/filter

```
df.withColumn('filtercol',percentile_approx('item_sum', 0.5, 100).over(Window.partitionBy())).where(col('item')<=col('filtercol')).show()


+----+--------+---------+
|item|item_sum|filtercol|
+----+--------+---------+
|   1|       1|        4|
|   2|       2|        4|
|   3|       3|        4|
|   4|       4|        4|
+----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: I'm using pyspark 2, percentile_approx supported only from pyspark 3.